# How to get selected value of DropDownList in Post method MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I'm a beginner in asp.net MVC. I have made a List property in the model which I'm updating in the Get Method. I'm binding that to the drop-down list in view using ViewBag. I'm trying to get the selected value of the dropdown list in the post method.

Below is the approach.

```
//UserRole Model

public UserRole()
{
     UsersNotInRole = new List<string>();
}
    public string Id { get; set; }     
    public List<string> UsersNotInRole { get; set; }
}
```

Updating list in UsersInRole [HttpGet] Action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> UsersInRole(string roleId, string roleName)
{

     //Finds the role associated with the specified roleId if any.
      var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);


            //initialize the model properties
       var model = new UserRole
       {
           Id = role.Id
       };
//add the users not in the role to the UsersNotInRole property in model
            foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
            {
                if (!await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                   model.UsersNotInRole.Add(user.UserName);

                }
            }
//Binding list to the drop-down list in view using ViewBag
ViewData["UsersNotInRole"] = new SelectList(model.UsersNotInRole);
return View(model);
}
```

AddUserToRole POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToRole(string roleId, string userName) //userName?? selected from UserNotInRole list
{
  var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                TempData["message"] = $"User selected cannot be found";
                return RedirectToAction("UsersInRole", new { roleId = role.Id.ToString(), roleName = role.Name.ToString() });
            }
            // Add user to role
            IdentityResult addResult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, userName);

return RedirectToAction("UsersInRole");
}
```

//View

```
@model UserRole
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = $"Users In Role";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label">Users not in role: </label>
                <select asp-for="UsersNotInRole" class="form-control" asp- 
                     items="ViewBag.UsersNotInRole"></select>
                <button type="submit" asp-action="AddUserToRole" asp-route-roleId="@Model.Id" class="btn 
                  btn-primary"> Add to Role</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of select tag in you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, ViewData["UsersNotInRole"] as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your form tag an action and controller address, then put an input with submit type (or button), then pass your model as an input to the post action.
when user clicks the submit input (or button), model with users data gets back to the post action, the id of the dropdown gets back as well as other properties of the model.

```
<form method="post" action="/controller/action">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add to Role</button>  
</form>
```

and to show your dropdown, you can use @Html.DropDown() in your view. if you dont know how to work with that, use below link.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

and your action post should be this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToRole(UserRole model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("UsersInRole");
}
```